# Excel Dropdown List: Set neighboring Cell based on value selected for first cell

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, listbox, spreadsheet, excel-2013

I have a column set to 'Data Validation', 'List', 'In-Cell Dropdown'.  This is referencing a source on another sheet.  Basically, I'm pulling our Active Directory use list and OUs into a second sheet in the workbook.  The 'Users' column in the main 'Combinded' sheet is a drop down list with a source of =Users!$A$2:$A$130.

When a user is selected in the User Column (say, 'Combined'!E2) and a record is selected from the other sheet, say, 'Users'!A2, I would like 'Combined'!F2 to then equal 'Users'!B2 without having to perform any additional action.  Is that possible?

I am using Excel 2013 and have the 'Power Query' module installed if that helps any!

Comment: Use the `VLOOKUP()` function in cell `F2`. The value to be looked up is cell `E2` and the lookup range will be `Users!$A$2:$B$130`.

Comment: @DMM Thanks, that appears to have done the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@DMM's comment to use VLOOKUP() was exactly what I was looking for!